# Swift: Delay loading animations in collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, imessage-extension

I have not seen this topic posted anywhere else - I have built an iMessage app that uses a collecitonview to hold a bunch of MSStickerViews. These stickers are animated.

My problem is that while the app itself appears to load when you first open, there is a noticeable delay before one is able to touch a sticker/interact with the app, and before the MSStickers begin animating. I am not sure whether this is a matter of the order of functions being called but I can't find a way to improve/fix this.

My MSStickers are added to collection view cells here:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "stickerCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! StickerCollectionViewCell
```

and in a separate Cell class I then add the sticker view and set it to `.startAnimating()`.

The delay is about 5-6 seconds. How can I reduce this? Is this possible?

Animation/sticker code:

```
 for (animal, atlas) in animalsAnim {
            animalsAnim[animal] = getImagesForAnimals(animal: animal, allSticks: allStickers)
            addSticker(images: animalsAnim[animal]!, name: animal)
        }

func addSticker(images: [UIImage], name: String)
    {
        let sticker: MSSticker
        do {
            try sticker=MSSticker(images: images, format: .apng, frameDelay: 0.95/14.0, numberOfLoops: 0, localizedDescription: name)
        }catch MSStickerAnimationInputError.InvalidDimensions {
            fatalError("ERROR: Dimens")
        }catch MSStickerAnimationInputError.InvalidStickerFileSize {
           fatalError("ERROR: Size")
        } catch { fatalError("other error:\(error)") }

        var stickerSize = CGSize()

        if (UIDevice.current.iPhone5orBefore)
        {

            stickerSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width*0.38, height: view.bounds.width*0.38)
        }
        else {
            stickerSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width*0.4, height: view.bounds.width*0.4)
        }

        let stickerView = InstrumentedStickerView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: stickerSize))

        stickerView.sticker = sticker
        stickerView.delegate = self

        stickerPack.append(stickerView)
    }
```

The sticker view is then added and begun animating in a separate cell class.

Comment: Does the delay occur every time or only the first time you open the stickers page?

Comment: Only when I first open the app - Like I'll go to iMessage and if I haven't had the app view up, it will delay

Comment: I don't think that is a problem with your code. I opened up my iMessage app and I experienced the same problem. When I open the game menu for the first time it lags for a few seconds. But when I come back to it when the app is still open the menu has no delay. However, if your delay is longer then 2-3 second then you might have too many animations.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Ive compressed my images all I can - is there anything else I can do to reduce this lag due to animation?

Comment: Can you add your code for your animations? And say how many animations you have.

Comment: See above. I have about 12 animated stickers